# .Net core 5 web api send file in content header?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm migrating a solution to the newest .Net core version but having some trouble.
I'm trying to find a way to put a zip file including it's checksum hash inside the content header of a response in .Net core 5 web api.
I'm doing this so that i can check the Zip integrity on the client side

I have the following code in .Net 4.7.2 :

Controller:

```
httpResponseMessage = httpRequestMessage.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = FileName;
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentMD5 = mD5Bytes;
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
```

And with the client i pick it out like this:

```
string destFolder = "C:\\SourceDotNet\\ReceiveLayouts\\";
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(destFolder);
                var resultFile = result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
                var resultFileName = result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
                var resultHash = result.Content.Headers.ContentMD5;
                var localHash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(resultFile);
```

And then compare the hashes, if they are the same then write file to disk.

My question is, what is the .Net core 5 variant of this approach?
There is no result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition
and no result.Content.Headers.ContentMD5 in .Net core 5..
It feels like i'm missing something..

***EDIT***
Ok now i know the following works:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            Byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\SourceDotNet\\ResourceZipFolder\\Resources.zip");
            String file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            var mD5Bytes = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(bytes);            
            Response.ContentType = "asd";
            
            return File(bytes, "application/octet-stream", "FileNameHere");
            
        }
```

But i still don't know how to get the Hash of the file inside the response, to compare integrity client side..

Comment: Don't you mean "send file *metadata* in content header"?

Comment: FYI it's ".Net 5" not ".Net Core 5" but it is "ASP.Net Core 5"!!!!

Comment: Yeah confusing isn't it

Comment: but why do you need to send it in content header but not in response?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i learned that checking checksum after a file transfer with https is redundant.

The way i still got it working is with the following code:

```
var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tempFileFullPath);
        var sha256 = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(bytes);
        Response.Headers.Add("FileHash", Convert.ToBase64String(sha256));
        
        Directory.Delete(tempFolder.FullName, true);
        
        return File(bytes, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
```

Then client side i pluck these details out, compare checksum and voila.